# iOS NSDictionary pass through function

Tags: ios, function, nsdictionary, viewcontroller

I have my view controller named SecondViewController and when user selects which article wants to read, I want to navigate to ThirdViewController and pass NSDictionary with article data.

```
- (void) touchButtonBlock:(NSInteger) select
{

    NSLog(@"touchButtonBlock");
    NSDictionary *dict;
    switch (select) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSMutableDictionary *val = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [val setObject:@"article360.html" forKey:@"page"];
            [val setObject:@"img.png" forKey:@"img"];
            [val setObject:@"art1" forKey:@"name"];

            [tmpDict setObject:val forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

            val = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [val setObject:@"article360.html" forKey:@"page"];
            [val setObject:@"img.png" forKey:@"img"];
            [val setObject:@"art2" forKey:@"name"];

            [tmpDict setObject:val forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

            dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:tmpDict];

            //[tmpDict release];
            //[val release];
            break;
        }
    NSDictionary *immDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];

    ArticleSelectListViewController *selectorView = [[ArticleSelectListViewController alloc] initWithArticlesData:immDict];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectorView animated:YES];
    [selectorView release];
}
```

Here I assing NSDicitionary:

```
- (id)initWithArticlesData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        articles = data;

    ...
}
```

But in the other functions that are being called after user interaction articles variable seems to be incorrect - it doesn't contain my data.

Where do I make mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of dictionary and then assign it.

```
 - (id)initWithArticlesData:(NSDictionary *)data
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        if (self)
        {
            articles = [data copy];

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***FIRST OPTION***

Use this function...

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil articles:(NSDictionary *)article
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.articles = article;
    }
    return self;
}
```

For push use this...

```
NSDictionary *immDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];

ArticleSelectListViewController *selectorView = [[ArticleSelectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ArticleSelectListViewController" bundle:nil articles:immDict];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:selectorView animated:YES];
[selectorView release];//FOR NON ARC
```

> ***SECOND OPTION***

Just use this..

```
NSDictionary *immDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];

ArticleSelectListViewController *selectorView = [[ArticleSelectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ArticleSelectListViewController" bundle:nil];
selectorView.articles = immDict;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:selectorView animated:YES];
[selectorView release];//FOR NON ARC
```