# Data being lost after passing between functions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having problem here regarding data lost on NSDictionary (or whatever data type I am trying to pass between view controllers). I am passing the data as I will show on code below. But after passing and then accessing the data again, I received a `null` object.

`FirstViewController.m`

```
-(void)showSecondViewController{
  SecondViewController *secondVC = [SecondViewController new];
  NSMutableDictionary *passedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [passedData setObject:@"First Object" forKey:@"first_obj"];
  [passedData setObject:@"Second Object" forKey:@"second_obj"];
  [secondVC setData:passedData];
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerSegue" sender:self];
}
```

In my `SecondViewController.h`

```
 @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
   NSDictionary *passedDataContainer;
}

-(void)setData(NSDictionary *)data;
```

And on `SecondViewController.m`

```
-(void)setData(NSDictionary *)data{
   passedDataContainer = data;
}
```

From this I am assuming that I have my `NSDictionary` from my `FirstViewController`, but when I used it, say for example...

```
-(void)usePassedData{
  NSLog(@"Display Passed Data from FirstViewController: %@",passedDataContainer);
}
```

In this code snippet, the output will be

```
Display Passed Data from FirstViewController: (null)
```

I hope I have explained the case well. I have checked some possible fixes that I found here on SO like for example, this post ---> [iOS NSDictionary pass through function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461189/ios-nsdictionary-pass-through-function).  I will be glad if I will know what is the cause of this, I am new to Objective-C.

P.S. I am using ARC.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use a property?

Comment: This tutorial link may help you: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this, hope this helps u :)

in your `SecondViewController.h`

```
 @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
 {
   NSDictionary *passedDataContainer;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *data;
```

and in `SecondViewController.m`

```
   @synthesize data; //just synthesize it
```

and your `FirstViewController.m`

```
-(void)showSecondViewController{
 SecondViewController *secondVC = [SecondViewController new];
 NSMutableDictionary *passedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [passedData setObject:@"First Object" forKey:@"first_obj"];
 [passedData setObject:@"Second Object" forKey:@"second_obj"];
  secondVC.data = passedData; //[secondVC setData:passedData];//change this
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the data from secondviewcontroller to first view controller then you can used CUSTOM DELEGATE , using custome delegate you can pass the data from secondviewcintroller to firstviewcontroller.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c) link may be helpful to you.
This is [second](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/) link to understand the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve for your solution.

> 1. NSUserDefaults.
> 2. Delegates(Custom).

**For Your problem :**. `Use the @PRoperty (Strong) reference to the NSDictionary and refer it from FirstViewController with the proper alloc of instance of SecondViewController.`

Answer (score 0):

Form your explanation, you are using `storyboard segue` to transition from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`. You need to pass data in `prepareForSegue` method instead of `showSecondViewController` method.

try this

```
FirstViewController.m

-(void)showSecondViewController{

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondViewControllerSegue"]){
     NSMutableDictionary *passedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [passedData setObject:@"First Object" forKey:@"first_obj"];
     [passedData setObject:@"Second Object" forKey:@"second_obj"];

     SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [secondVC setData:passedData];
}
```

In  `SecondViewController.h`

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *data;
```

In  `SecondViewController.m`

```
-(void)usePassedData{
  NSLog(@"Display Passed Data from FirstViewController: %@",data);
}
```